# Exchange Server 2010 - How do i set up mailboxes which can be accessed in outlook by other employees

Tags: exchange-2010

i am trying to set up a mailbox named accounts and give another user Andrea access to attach the accounts mailbox via her outlook.  Can someone please advise me how to assign permissions to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the mailbox, "Manage Full Access Permissions".

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Erik said, Go to the Exchange Management Console -> Recipients -> Mailboxes -> Right-click on the mailbox, and "Manage Full Access Permissions." Then select the user (Andrea) you want to grant access to, and add them.

On the user side, just go through Account Settings and in the Advanced tab for Andrea's account, there is a space to add additional mailboxes. Add in the mailbox you've created and it should appear in her sidebar under her regular account.

Comment: Hi ErikA and Rob

Thank you for your quick response i have now been able to add the permissions to the account.